# Issue while copying tables on PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

All id are auto_increment. I will try explain my issue understandable. I just want copy 2 tables to another 2 tables. Here my tables at below:

`table1`

```
id  number

10   100
11   102
12   105
13   106
```

`table2`

```
id  number_id   subnumber

52     10           10
53     11           15
54     13           40
```

You can see there is subnumber of some numbers. For example, WHERE id =11 from `table1` has a subnumber on `table2` and it is equal to 15. Now I should copy the `table1` to the table : `copy_table1`

```
$sql1 = mysql_query('INSERT INTO
          copy_table1 (copy_number)
        SELECT
          number
        FROM
          table1');
```

And the results of copy_table1 are:

`copy_table1`

```
id      copy_number
100      100
101      102
102      105  
103      106
```

Then I should copy `table2` to another table `copy_table2`:

```
$sql2 = mysql_query('INSERT INTO
          copy_table2 (copy_number_id, copy_subnumber)
        SELECT
          number_id, copy_subnumber
        FROM
          table2');
```

And the results of `copy_table2` are:

```
id  copy_number_id   copy_subnumber
60        10              10
61        11              15
62        13              40
```

So, lets check the tables: `copy_table1` and `copy_table2`. 
You see, ID from `copy_table1` is not equal and suitable to copy_number_id FROM `copy_table2`
And it brings me problem. How can I do that after copying tables id and copy_number_id  will be suitable to each other?

Comment: write a store procedure or use your preferred language, you need to loop and then run insert, i.e. insert first table, as you want, then search new id of your record and replace that in second query.

Comment: This is the long WAY man. I think I can do it on second sql using JOIN. but I tried, there is no result

Comment: I am not sure if there is any method with just query exists, but I don't believe there exist anything as what you want is "business logic" and Query are for Database operation. so logic must be done logical way only.

Comment: just a thought, you can do this if you preserve the Original key in Destination table 1, i.e. make extra column in destination table then using join you can do that.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Right now I gonna do it

Comment: I have done it, already. LOOK AT MY ANswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql2=mysql_query('INSERT INTO
   copy_table2 (copy_number_id, copy_subnumber)
SELECT DISTINCT
   cp1.id, t2.subnumber
FROM
   copy_table1 AS cp1
CROSS JOIN
   table1 AS t1
USING (number)
INNER JOIN
   table2 AS t2
ON
   t1.id = t2.number_id ');
```

Comment: I have fixed my problem by myself